# How to split a string with more than one delimiter in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this =

```
str = (((MY (NAME IS) IS) YOUR NAME)
```

I want to split all the values in this string to get a result like this:

```
lst = ['(', '(', '(', 'MY', '(', 'NAME', 'IS', ')', 'IS', ')', 'YOUR', 'NAME', ')']
```

Is it possible to split the string like this with more than one delimiter?

Answer (score 7):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(((MY (NAME IS) IS) YOUR NAME)'
>>> re.findall(r'[()]|[a-zA-Z]+', s)
['(', '(', '(', 'MY', '(', 'NAME', 'IS', ')', 'IS', ')', 'YOUR', 'NAME', ')']
```

A non-regex solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def solve(s):
    for k, g in groupby(s, str.isalpha):
        if k:
            yield ''.join(g)
        else:
            for x in g:
                if not x.isspace():
                    yield x
...                     
>>> list(solve(s))
['(', '(', '(', 'MY', '(', 'NAME', 'IS', ')', 'IS', ')', 'YOUR', 'NAME', ')']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work out.

```
my_string = "(((MY (NAME IS) IS) YOUR NAME)"
char_list = []

for char in my_string:
    char_list.append(char)

print(char_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).